# CSS How to center link elements within a div

Tags: css

So I have a div which will contain 3 buttons and I want these buttons centered within the div.

I tried this so far

```
.centerButtons  
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 90%;    
}
```

Which centers the div containing the buttons which is fine, but the actual buttons within this div are not centered..This is my mark up so far..

```
<div class="clearfixLeft clearfix centerButtons">
  <xsl:if test="sc:fld('Link One', .)!=''">
    <div class="fl_left mr_7 mt_10">
      <div class="green-btn-solid">
        <sc:link field="Link One">
          <span class="btnspan">
            <sc:text select="." field="Link One Text" />
          </span>
        </sc:link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:if>
  ...
</div>
```

Additional Classes

```
/* link styles */
.green-btn-solid {line-height: 21px; height: 21px; background: url(../../images/SOURCE/btn_grn_r.gif) 100% 0 no-repeat; width: auto; display: block; padding-right: 30px; }
.green-btn-solid span {display: block; float: left; background: url(../../images/SOURCE/btn_grn_l.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; line-height: 21px; height: 21px; padding-left: 12px; color: #fff;}
```

Comment: Just to be sure - have you tried `text-align:center;`?

Comment: <center> tag isn't fine as being the parent of your 3div?

Comment: @HamzaWaqas: Don't. It's deprecated since HTML4: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks mate! I wasn't aware of it :)

Comment: Applying <div align="center"> wouldn't work again?

Comment: @HamzaWaqas: `align` is deprecated too :D http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#adef-align - like almost all attributes for alignment, fonts, colors, borders, backgrounds. Almost everything not semantic but stylistic is deprecated since HTML4 and has been moved into CSS.

Comment: I think I must go ahead to skip from HTML anymore :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried text-align: center;?  I'm pretty sure it works on elements as well.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align)

```
.centerButtons {
    text-align: center;
}
```

which will center all inline children of class `centerButtons`

Comment: When I try text-align center it it no longer center my 90% div and just everything is pushed to the left

Comment: @StevieB: Please post all classes involved in your current example, such as `fl_left`, `mr_7`, `mt_10`,...

Comment: .fl_left { float: left; } .mr_7 { margin-right: 7px; }   .mt_10  { margin-top: 10px; } and I added the button class around my href in original

Answer (score 2):

`text-align` on the `centerButtons` class will work if your button is an inline element. If your button is a block-level element, you will need to define it's width and use `margin: auto` like you did with the `centerButtons` element.

Comment: My buttons within that div are just links really I added the CSS for the link style in original post...green-btn-solid...so they are block from the look of it, I tried adding the margin auto there but had no effect

Comment: Adding `margin: auto` will not center an element unless that element has a defined width. Your element's width is defined as `auto`, so it will not be centered. You should define it precisely, for example `width: 100px;` or `width: 100%;`.