# How to center hyperlinks within a DIV?

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, center

I have a set of hyperlinks (using the a tag) that are placed within a DIV and I would like them to center within that DIV. I have tried putting text-align (Italicized) on this DIV and have also tried margin 0 auto (Italicized) for the hyperlinks but they still stick firmly to the left.

Below is the HTML and the CSS code.

Thanks for the help!

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
        <a class="nav" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="nav" href="Page 1.html">Page 1</a>
        <a class="nav" href="Page 2.html">Page 2</a>
        <a class="nav" href="Page 3.html">Page 3</a>
        <a class="nav" href="Page 4.html">Page 4</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation {
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
border: #000 solid 1px;
    *text-align: center;*
}

.nav {
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 80px;
height: 40px;
background-color: #0F0; 
    *margin: 0 auto;*
}
```

Comment: Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/e6rgb/ ?

Comment: @drip exactly like that except when I do it like that (or copy that coding into Dreamweaver the height and width properties for the hyperlinks seem to get ignored.

Comment: remove the float and change block to inline. Is this more like what you need?
edit: sorry, just realized this was in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @elk thanks, drips first example was perfect it seems there was nothing wrong with the coding I just got tricked by Dreamweaver's design view.

Comment: @drip thanks, the first example was perfect it seems there was nothing wrong with the coding I just got tricked by Dreamweaver's design view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS How to center link elements within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916847/css-how-to-center-link-elements-within-a-div)

Answer (score 3):

Remove `float:left` from `.nav` class and add `display:inline-block`

```
.nav {
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 80px;
height: 40px;
background-color: #0F0; 
}
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uhwA5/1/)**

Comment: This doesn't work as the links then appear as stacked elements. This can be improved by changing the display to inline-block however the height and width values are then ignored.

Comment: @Tom I'm already using `display:inline-block` and where the height and width values are ignored. I can see the changes in height and width.

Comment: Ah yes I see this now but it seems that it was an issue with Dreamweaver design view as oppose to the code. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Tom great; glad to help you. yes it might be possible that there are some other style preventing you to do that in your Dreamweaver code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the float.

Floated elements can not be centered using `margin: 0 auto;`. Adding float to a element makes it a block element. `text-align: center` doesn't affect block elements. It does affect inline-block though.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Float: left fromy our a(.nav) and add the Text-align: center to your div.

Answer (score -1):

There are so many ways you can achieve that but I think that you should read this [post](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/) by Joshua Johnson at design shack so that you will learn more about [how to center anything](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/).